# Comparing a Java ArrayList within a JSF Page

Tags: jsf, arraylist

I would like to check whether an arrayList contains a specific element within a JSF.

ArrayList is nonTradList containing couple of values.
sProcessorView is the instance of Java class

JSF page is something like below -

```
<h:commandButton id="p"
                 value="#{msgs['SP.Pend.Button.Label']}" 
                 type="button"
                 disabled="#{securityView.readOnlyUser or sPView.readOnly}">
    <rich:toolTip style="white-space:nowrap" value="Ctrl-Shft-P" />
    <a4j:support event="onclick"
                 oncomplete="if ((!#{sProcessorView.autoFetchNext}) &amp;&amp; 
                                   #{sProcessorView.nonTradList.contains('100')} &amp;&amp;
                                   #{spProcessorView.nonTradList.contains('111')} ) openSimplePop() ; 
                             else openModal();" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Is there any EL is already there or I have to write some custom tag?

Can we also call a Java method from this JSF to get the result?

Any help is really appreciated on this

Comment: That code should work just fine, provided that you're using EL 2.2 or JBoss EL and that the `ArrayList` contains `String` items. What exactly is the concrete problem you're facing? You didn't describe that in any way in your question. An SSCCE would be very helpful if you have a hard time in English.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method on your ManagedBean that returns a boolean

```
public boolean containsValue() {
   //Check if the value is in the list...
}
```

And on your page, you can do this:

```
var showModal = #{bean.containsValue()};
if(showModal) {
   openModal();
} else openSimplePop();
```

Doing this way, you can check if the list on your ManagedBean contains the value, if so the method will return true, which will be set on the JS variable.